# applying regex to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm having trouble applying a regex function a column in a python dataframe.  Here is the head of my dataframe:

```
               Name   Season          School   G    MP  FGA  3P  3PA    3P%
 74       Joe Dumars  1982-83   McNeese State  29   NaN  487   5    8  0.625   
 84      Sam Vincent  1982-83  Michigan State  30  1066  401   5   11  0.455   
 176  Gerald Wilkins  1982-83     Chattanooga  30   820  350   0    2  0.000   
 177  Gerald Wilkins  1983-84     Chattanooga  23   737  297   3   10  0.300   
 243    Delaney Rudd  1982-83     Wake Forest  32  1004  324  13   29  0.448
```

I thought I had a pretty good grasp of applying functions to Dataframes, so maybe my Regex skills are lacking.

Here is what I put together:

```
import re

def split_it(year):
    return re.findall('(\d\d\d\d)', year)

 df['Season2'] = df['Season'].apply(split_it(x))

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Output would be a column called Season2 that contains the year before the hyphen.  I'm sure theres an easier way to do it without regex, but more importantly, i'm trying to figure out what I did wrong

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When I try (a variant of) your code I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`-- which it isn't.

You could use either

```
df['Season2'] = df['Season'].apply(split_it)
```

or

```
df['Season2'] = df['Season'].apply(lambda x: split_it(x))
```

but the second one is just a longer and slower way to write the first one, so there's not much point (unless you have other arguments to handle, which we don't here.)  Your function will return a *list*, though:

```
>>> df["Season"].apply(split_it)
74     [1982]
84     [1982]
176    [1982]
177    [1983]
243    [1982]
Name: Season, dtype: object
```

although you could easily change that.  FWIW, I'd use vectorized string operations and do something like

```
>>> df["Season"].str[:4].astype(int)
74     1982
84     1982
176    1982
177    1983
243    1982
Name: Season, dtype: int64
```

or

```
>>> df["Season"].str.split("-").str[0].astype(int)
74     1982
84     1982
176    1982
177    1983
243    1982
Name: Season, dtype: int64
```

Comment: realized i asked the question wrong and had what you gave me.  my error was coming b/c i had NaN values in the year further down the dataframe.  I found that out by trying df["Season"].str.split("-").str[0].astype(int).  Thanks anyways though, really appreciate it

Comment: when I want to lowercase the values, ```df['Season2'] = df['Season'].apply(lower())``` doesn't work, I have to use lambda

Answer (score 34):

You can simply use `str.extract`

```
df['Season2']=df['Season'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})-\d{2}')
```

Here you locate `\d{4}-\d{2}` (for example 1982-83) but only extracts the captured group between parenthesis `\d{4}` (for example 1982)

Comment: Is case there are more than one matches, is there a way to separate the matches with a ```,``` ?

Answer (score 11):

The asked problem can be solved by writing the following code :

```
import re
def split_it(year):
    x = re.findall('([\d]{4})', year)
    if x :
      return(x.group())

df['Season2'] = df['Season'].apply(split_it)
```

You were facing this problem as some rows didn't had year in the string

Answer (score 3):

you can use pandas native function to do it too.

check [this page](https://kanoki.org/2019/11/12/how-to-use-regex-in-pandas/) for the pandas functions that accepts regular expression. for your case, you can do

```
df["Season"].str.extract(r'([\d]{4}))')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Thanks for the answers @DSM. 
FYI @itjcms, you can improve the function by removing the repetition of the `'\d\d\d\d'`.

```
def split_it(year):  
    return re.findall('(\d\d\d\d)', year)
```

Becomes:

```
def split_it(year):
    return re.findall('(\d{4})', year)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd extract with:

```
df['Season2']=df['Season'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}))
```