# Pandas Dataframe check if a value exists using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe and I want to check if any cell contains `admin` string.

```
   col1                   col2 ... coln
0   323           roster_admin ... rota_user
1   542  assignment_rule_admin ... application_admin
2   123           contact_user ... configuration_manager
3   235         admin_incident ... incident_user
... ...  ...                   ... ...
```

I tried to use `df.isin(['*admin*']).any()` but it seems like `isin` doesn't support regex. How can I search though all columns using regex?

I have avoided using loops because the dataframe contains over 10 million rows and many columns and the efficiency is important for me.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292838/applying-regex-to-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `df.isin(vals)` checks whether the DataFrame/Series values *are in* the `vals`. Here `vals` must be **set or list-like**. I don't think `df.isin(vals)` is the natural way to check if a `vals` contained in a DataFrame column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. `df.col.apply` method is more straightforward but also a little bit slower:

   ```
   In [1]: import pandas as pd

   In [2]: import re

   In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':['admin', 'aa', 'bb', 'c_admin_d', 'ee_admin']})

   In [4]: df
   Out[4]: 
      col1       col2
   0     1      admin
   1     2         aa
   2     3         bb
   3     4  c_admin_d
   4     5   ee_admin

   In [5]: r = re.compile(r'.*(admin).*')

   In [6]: df.col2.apply(lambda x: bool(r.match(x)))
   Out[6]: 
   0     True
   1    False
   2    False
   3     True
   4     True
   Name: col2, dtype: bool

   In [7]: %timeit -n 100000 df.col2.apply(lambda x: bool(r.match(x)))
   167 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
   ```

---

2. `np.vectorize` method require `import numpy`, but it's more efficient (about 4 times faster in my `timeit` test).

   ```
   In [1]: import numpy as np

   In [2]: import pandas as pd

   In [3]: import re

   In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':['admin', 'aa', 'bb', 'c_admin_d', 'ee_admin']})

   In [5]: df
   Out[5]: 
      col1       col2
   0     1      admin
   1     2         aa
   2     3         bb
   3     4  c_admin_d
   4     5   ee_admin

   In [6]: r = re.compile(r'.*(admin).*')

   In [7]: regmatch = np.vectorize(lambda x: bool(r.match(x)))

   In [8]: regmatch(df.col2.values)
   Out[8]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])

   In [9]: %timeit -n 100000 regmatch(df.col2.values)
   43.4 µs ± 362 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
   ```

---

Since you have changed your question to check any cell, and also concern about time efficiency:

```
# if you want to check all columns no mater what `dtypes` they are
dfs = df.astype(str, copy=True, errors='raise')
regmatch(dfs.values) # This will return a 2-d array of booleans
regmatch(dfs.values).any() # For existence.
```

You can still use `df.applymap` method, but again, it will be slower.

```
dfs = df.astype(str, copy=True, errors='raise')
r = re.compile(r'.*(admin).*')
dfs.applymap(lambda x: bool(r.match(x))) # This will return a dataframe of booleans.
dfs.applymap(lambda x: bool(r.match(x))).any().any() # For existence.
```

Comment: what if the value a column is a list, for example `'col2':[['aa','admin'],['admin_b']..]`?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': [323,542,123,235],
     'col2': ['roster_admin','assignment_rule_admin','contact_user','admin_incident'] ,
    })

df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('admin').any(), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is unacceptably slow for me. I was waiting over 5 minutes and eventually gave up. `isin` takes around 5 seconds.

Comment: @MichaelDz Do we have to check for word admin in only Col 2?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention in the original post that I want to search through all the columns.

Comment: @MichaelDz Even check for `col1`? Which only contains numbers and have `dtype` as `int64`? Or you have a dataframe contains mix data types in columns?

Comment: I have a mixed data.

Comment: @MichaelDz Well, in this case, you have to use `astype` method first.

Comment: @MichaelDz did you use `isin` with a regex? i haven't found a way to do that yet.