# How to delete rows from pd series or dataframe based on regex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Actually it should be quite simple. I have a pd series bar['Barcode'] where I want to get filter eans (barcodes with 12, 13 or 14 digits) from. Using Regex i'm appending to a new list within a loop. How do I at the same time delete the rows from the original series?

```
bar = pd.read_csv("barcode.csv", header=0, sep=';', engine='python')

ean = []
for i in bar['Barcode']:
    x = re.search("\d{12,14}", i)
    if(x):
        ean.append(x.group())
        #bar.drop(bar['Barcode']==x.string, inplace=True)
print(ean)
```

The problem comes with the line that I commented out. This is not the right way to do it, but I don't know how what else is possible. Could you help me delete the rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Providing an excerpt of `barcode['Barcode']` may help.

Comment: note: this is very close to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25292838/1358308

Answer (score 0):

I'd just accumulate everything to a list and drop afterwards, mutating an object while you're iterating it is asking for trouble!

to start with, make it into a MWE:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(i, '1' * i) for i in range(10, 17)],
    columns=['i', 'barcode']
)
```

which gives us a simple dataframe with two columns, we can then go the verbose route of defining a function to do the matching and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)ing this
to the column:

```
def match(s):
    m = re.match(r'^\d{12,14}$', s)
    if m:
        return m.group()

df['match'] = df['barcode'].apply(match)
```

note I use a `r` at the beginning of the string to turn off escaping, and use `^` and `$` to match beginning and end of strings.

you can then use this to filter the dataframe:

```
df[~df['match'].isnull()]
```

which gives us our three rows back that match.

if you want a one-liner and don't care about the matched string, you could do:

```
df[df['barcode'].apply(lambda s: re.match(r'^\d{12,14}$', s) is not None)]
```

but I'd say code like this is bordering on the unreadable